# Retrieve upper and lower rows where the middle row matches a pattern?

Tags: text-processing

I have a data set (e.g., a file) that looks like this:

```
4.048   5.9392765
4.051   5.9392765
4.068   5.9392765
4.293   5.9392765
4.3 "A random string"
4.331   5.9392765
4.429   6.0137865
4.609   6.0303125
4.662   6.0303125
5.626   6.1261205
5.815   6.1261205
6.347   6.1261205
6.543   6.1261205
6.7 "A random string"
7.420   6.1611095
7.526   6.2542085
7.541   6.2698285
7.556   6.2698285
7.928   6.2698285
```

I want to extract groups of three lines (rows)
where the second field of the middle row is a string rather than a number. 
For example, for the above input, I'd like to get the following output:

```
4.293   5.9392765
4.3 "A random string"
4.331   5.9392765
------------------------
6.543   6.1261205
6.7 "A random string"
7.420   6.1611095
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I found your question hard to understand.  If I misunderstood it, please re-[edit] it to fix it.

Comment: @G-Man: Thank you for your response and your edit. It absolutely looks more comprehensible now!

Comment: Yeah, (1) “dataframe” is uncommon terminology, (2) I felt that “upper and lower rows” needed clarification, and (3) a computer can subtract 4607111701851759477 from 4607111701951759477 in less time than it takes a person to type a key. But people have trouble looking at long strings of digits and seeing the difference quickly. It’s better to give examples using small numbers and short strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`grep`** solution:

```
grep -C1 -E '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[[:space:]]+[^0-9[:space:]]+' file
```

- `-C NUM` - print `NUM` lines of output context
- `-E` - extended regexp
- `[^0-9[:space:]]+` - match any character except whitespace(s) `[:space:]` or digit `[0-9]`

---

The output:

```
51174.29300 2265.9392765
51174.3 "A random string"
51174.33100 2265.9392765
--
51176.54300 2266.1261205
51176.7 "A random string"
51177.42000 2266.1611095
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler answer:

```
grep -C1 '"' file
```

which finds the lines containing a quote character (`"`) and displays them,
with one line before and after.